# Android indoor map using image generates different path from point a to b depending on destination's input (No use of indoor navigation technologies)

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, svg, navigation

I'm working on an android app for my final year project and I'm unsure how to solve this problem. I would like some advices to get me started in the right direction.

The project is to develop an android app to output a direction path from point a to point b on an image representing a two dimensional indoor map. The direction displayed  will be  depending on the user's input (destination). The starting point will always be the same location on the image. Once the user select a specific object, the app should find its location on the map using a database and then draw the direction's path from Point "a" to point "b".

I do not want to use any indoor navigation technology for this app. The location of each object on the map should be predefined and stored in a database.

The part which I am really unsure about is how to do the following for and android app. --> How to predefine points on an image and how to use these predefined data to display the path to take in the image representing the indoor map. I have been advised to use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics), I have found androidVG to use SVG with android but I haven't found much information on it.

I am currently clueless regarding what language and techniques to use  in order to perform the above feature on android.

Questions:

1) What general advice would you give me on how to effectively tackle this problem from the information I've provided?

2) Was I correctly advised when I have been given SVG as one of the language to use for the development of this app? If I was, would anybody have any more information on using SVG for android to provide me with?

3) IF there would be a better way to solve this problem which language should be used?

I really appreciate all the help provided in this community. Hopefully I have been clear enough, hoping to have my questions answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case I think it would be much simpler to just use the standard Canvas API to draw your lines rather than using an SVG renderer.

I would extend the Android `ImageView` class.  In the onDraw() method call `super.onDraw()` to let it plot the image.  Then add your lines using (for example) a set of `canvas.drawLine()` calls.